# python subset data frame by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python3. I have a data frame which looks like below:

col1, col2, col3

1,a,red

2,b,green

3,c,blue

4,d,yellow

I would like to subset this data frame by the value of col1. I want to find all the rows, the col1 value of which is in list [2,4]. The correct result should be

2,b,green

4,d,yellow

How could I write this code please?

Comment: It should not be that hard.. Loop through the list of lists, and then check if `col1 in [2, 4]`

Comment: `desired = [2,4]`
`df.query('col1 in @desired')`